Is the low pressure behind a (wetting) fluid meniscus local or global when the meniscus is pinned inside a filled capillary closed at one end?
I have not been able to resolve the following question, that has arisen in my experimental setup, despite extensive research. The many sources indirectly addressing a similar configuration seem contradictory in their statements.
Can someone clarify the relationship between the three pressures in my diagram and the ambient pressure? The capillary is intentionally laying on its side. Gravity can be ignored as the diameter of the capillary is ~40µm. No fluid is moving (except for evaporaiton). The pressure "P1" behind (across?) the pinned meniscus is theoretically considerable (Young-Laplace) and in the $ \,\text{-kPa}$ range (w.r.t. the ambient air at atmospheric pressure). Is the Laplace pressure "P1" behind the menicus transmitted to the remaining fluid, or is this a special case, where adhesive forces give rise to a local pressure that is lower than in the remaining capillary?

For bonus points, how is the "farfield" pressure modified by the addition of a second, smaller opening as in the arrangement below? Do the menisci influence each other and the overall pressure in the capillary?


$p_1$ pressure may be different due to capillary action (attraction of glass wall molecules). Farfield pressure is different because of different depth, as per $\rho g h$ (assuming counterclockwise rotated images)

The horizontal orientaiton is deliberate. Bond numbers are too small for gravity to play a non-ngeligibe role here compared to the surface tension forces.

Yes, if the liquid is at rest, pressure in the liquid at the same height is everywhere the same - Pascal's law.
If the liquid moves, then pressure can vary. If the liquid has very low viscosity, and liquid velocity is low enough, we can relate pressure to velocity of the liquid element via the Bernoulli equation:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + p = const.
$$

The fluid is at rest and gravity unimportant, as stated in the question.

@KUK Then plug in $v=0$ and you'll get the correct conclusion $p=const.$

Thanks for your efforts, I should have stated that I am interested in the relaitonship between the pressures and the ambient pressure. Static pressure in all cases. None of the fluids are moving. I will edit to reflect this.
